# LLamar desde un botón Swift 2 Xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode

Hola tengo el siguiente código que es para llamar desde un botón o abrir el dial para llamar en iOS el tema es que en mi proyecto tengo muchas pantallas y en cada una un botón que tiene que llamar a un número distinto. Mi consulta hay alguna forma de conectar todas las pantallas a un controller y colocar el codigo para llamar enlazado a cada botón o alguna otra forma mejor de aplicar el código a cada botón.

Swift

```
@IBAction func marcar(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let url = NSURL(string: "tel://0180032323") {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para manejar todo este tipo de situación, crear una clase `Utils` así:

```
class Utils: NSObject {
    class func call() {
        if let url = NSURL(string: "tel://0180032323") {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
        }
    }
}
```

Y llamarlo así desde cualquier parte de tu app:

```
Utils.call()
```

Answer (score 1):

el problema que veo es que es un ibaction, ese ibaction debe de mandar llamar a una funcion  y que esa funcion sea la que tenga el codigo

una ves en una funcion desde otro archivo de swift prueba con esto:

```
let llamar = PrimeraPantalla()
llamar.FuncionLlamada()
```

Comment: Es mejor no crear una pantalla del app solo para acceder a un método en especifico, para esto existe los métodos `class func`.